# GKE basic-ingress intermittently returns 502 when backend returns 404/422

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, http-response-codes

I have an ingress providing routing for two microservices running on GKE, and intermittently when the microservice returns a 404/422, the ingress returns a 502.

Here is my ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: basic-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: develop-static-ip
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: dev-ssl-cert
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: srv
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /c/*
        backend:
          serviceName: collection
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /w/*
        backend:
          serviceName: collection
          servicePort: 80
```

I run tests that hit the `srv` back-end where I expect a 404 or 422 response. I have verified when I hit the `srv` back-end directly (bypassing the ingress) that the service responds correctly with the 404/422.

When I issue the same requests through the ingress, the ingress will intermittently respond with a 502 instead of the 404/422 coming from the back-end.

How can I have the ingress just return the 404/422 response from the back-end?

Here's some example code to demonstrate the behavior I'm seeing (the expected status is 404):

```py
>>> for i in range(10):
        resp = requests.get('https://<server>/a/v0.11/accounts/junk', cookies=<token>)
        print(resp.status_code)

502
502
404
502
502
404
404
502
404
404
```

And here's the same requests issued from a python prompt within the pod, i.e. bypassing the ingress:

```py
>>> for i in range(10):
...     resp = requests.get('http://0.0.0.0/a/v0.11/accounts/junk', cookies=<token>)
...     print(resp.status_code)
...
404
404
404
404
404
404
404
404
404
404
```

Here's the output of the kubectl commands to demonstrate that the loadbalancer is set up correctly (I never get a 502 for a 2xx/3xx response from the microservice):

```sh
$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP          NODE                                     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
srv-799976fbcb-4dxs7          2/2     Running   0          19m   10.24.3.8   gke-develop-default-pool-ea507abc-43h7   <none>           <none>
srv-799976fbcb-5lh9m          2/2     Running   0          19m   10.24.1.7   gke-develop-default-pool-ea507abc-q0j3   <none>           <none>
srv-799976fbcb-5zvmv          2/2     Running   0          19m   10.24.2.9   gke-develop-default-pool-ea507abc-jjzg   <none>           <none>
collection-5d9f8586d8-4zngz   2/2     Running   0          19m   10.24.1.6   gke-develop-default-pool-ea507abc-q0j3   <none>           <none>
collection-5d9f8586d8-cxvgb   2/2     Running   0          19m   10.24.2.7   gke-develop-default-pool-ea507abc-jjzg   <none>           <none>
collection-5d9f8586d8-tzwjc   2/2     Running   0          19m   10.24.2.8   gke-develop-default-pool-ea507abc-jjzg   <none>           <none>
parser-7df86f57bb-9qzpn       1/1     Running   0          19m   10.24.0.8   gke-develop-parser-pool-5931b06f-6mcq    <none>           <none>
parser-7df86f57bb-g6d4q       1/1     Running   0          19m   10.24.5.5   gke-develop-parser-pool-5931b06f-9xd5    <none>           <none>
parser-7df86f57bb-jchjv       1/1     Running   0          19m   10.24.0.9   gke-develop-parser-pool-5931b06f-6mcq    <none>           <none>

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
srv          NodePort    10.0.2.110   <none>        80:30141/TCP   129d
collection   NodePort    10.0.4.237   <none>        80:30270/TCP   129d
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        130d

$ kubectl get endpoints
NAME         ENDPOINTS                                AGE
srv          10.24.1.7:80,10.24.2.9:80,10.24.3.8:80   129d
collection   10.24.1.6:80,10.24.2.7:80,10.24.2.8:80   129d
kubernetes   35.237.239.186:443                       130d
```

Comment: Have you checked the stackdriver log for 502 when you are getting the 502 http error response? What's the reason for this 502 as per stackdriver? Additionally, you have mentioned you are getting 502 intermittently, I am curious to know what other response code you are getting when it's not 502.

Comment: The stackdriver logs have no entries corresponding to these requests. When I don't get a 502, I get the 404 (or 422) as I expect. I added an example of the behavior I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr: GCP LoadBalancer/GKE Ingress will 502 if 404/422s from the back-ends don't have response bodies.

Looking at the LoadBalancer logs, I would see the following errors:

```
502: backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client
404: backend_connection_closed_after_partial_response_sent
```

Since everything was configured correctly (even the LoadBalancer said the backends were healthy)--backend was working as expected and no failed health checks--I experimented with a few things and noticed that all of my 404 responses had empty bodies.

Sooo, I added a body to my 404 and 422 responses and lo and behold no more 502s!

Answer (score 0):

502 is a tricky status code, it can mean a context cancelled by the client or simply a bad gateway from the server you are trying to reach. In kubernetes a 502 usually means you cannot reach the service. Thus, I would go for debugging your services and deployments [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/).

Use `kubectl get pods -o wide` to get your `srv` pod; check its clusterIP IP. Then make sure the service is load balancing the `srv` deployment. To accomplish this, run `kubectl get svc` and look for the `srv` service. Finally run `kubectl get endpoints`, get the IP assigned to the `srv` endpoint and match it against the IP you obtained from the pod. If this is all ok, then you are correctly load-balancing to your backend.

Comment: 2xx/3xx responses from the srv deployment all come through the ingress as expected. The behavior seems to be isolated to 404/422 responses. I added an example run to show the intermittent 502s, and I added the output from the kubectl commands. As far as I can tell, everything is set up correctly.

Comment: Intermitents 502s I have seen this before in stackoverflow and medium posts. Can you try doing the same but within the pod? Do not use the service. In this way we could determine whether is the deployment or the service.

Comment: Added the output from running the same requests within the pod, and the responses are all 404s as expected. I've tried finding something similar in SO and medium but everything I have found corresponds to issues with a non-responsive back-end, which this is clearly not.

Answer (score 0):

[502 errors are expected when your backend service is returning 4xx errors](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts#criteria-protocol-http). If the backend is returning 4xx, the health checks will fail. If all backends are failing, the Load Balancer will not have an available backend to send the traffic to and will return 502.

For any 502 error returned from the Load Balancer, I strongly recommend checking the stackdriver logs for the HTTP Load Balancer. Any 502 error will include a message output along with the 502 response. The message should clarify why 502 was reutned (there are a number of reasons).

In your current case, the [502 error log should mention](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#what_is_logged) "failed_to_pick_backend" or "failed_to_connect_to_backend", something to that tune. If you are using nginx ingress, similar behavior can be seen, but the 502 error message may say something different.

Comment: The loadbalancer logs have this code for the 502: backend_connection_closed_before_data_sent_to_client. This behavior doesn't make sense to me. If a client requests a URL that doesn't exist, the back-end should return a 404.

Comment: You are absolutely right, that error makes no sense with 404 errors. That error is normally due to a mismatch between the TTL of the LB and the backend

Comment: Decided to look at what came back from the 404s too: backend_connection_closed_after_partial_response_sent. Turns out the LB doesn't like empty response bodies.